# After Migration from local to server only page title loading, Front page blank and Admin page 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, aws, curl

After migration to AWS server from local getting weird error. The front page of site showing complete blank page only page title is visible.

And Admin page showing 404 error. I am using Magento CE 1.9.x

Does curl required to active to resolve this?

Because i have tried all possible solutions. Like, Disabled compile mode, Deleted Cache files and removed comment from ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

If the title is showing, then it is likely that an error is being printed near the end of the HTML `<head>` element. You will need to View Source in your browser to see that error.